# React - Using Props outside of Render

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-props

I am trying to post a UserId to a database but the Id is passed as a prop. When I enter this.props.userId within the render method, it displays the desired information however when I try to incorporate it into a function above the render function I get null. I have spent hours reviewing other postings and trying what feels like everything I can to no avail.

**App.js Code**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Redirect,
} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import MyEvents from "./pages/MyEvents"
import Signup from "./pages/Signup";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Navbar from "./components/Navigation/Navigation";
import "./App.css"


class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      loggedIn: false,
      username: null,
      userId: null,
    }

    this.getUser = this.getUser.bind(this)
    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this)
    this.updateUser = this.updateUser.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUser()
  }

  updateUser (userObject) {
    this.setState(userObject)
  }

  getUser() {
    axios.get('/api/users/').then(response => {
      console.log('Get user response: ')
      console.log(response.data)
      if (response.data.user) {
        console.log('Get User: There is a user saved in the server session: ')

        this.setState({
          loggedIn: true,
          username: response.data.user.username,
          userId: response.data.user._id
        })
      } else {
        console.log('Get user: no user');
        this.setState({
          loggedIn: false,
          username: null,
          userId: null
        })
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <Navbar updateUser={this.updateUser} loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn} />
        {/* greet user if logged in: */}
        {this.state.loggedIn &&
          <p>You are logged in, {this.state.username}, userId: {this.state.userId}!!!!</p>
        }
        {/* Routes to different components */}
        <Route
          exact path="/home"
          render = {() => 
            <Home userId = {this.state.userId} />
          }
          />
```

***Home.js Code***

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import API from "../utils/API";
class Events extends Component {
  state = {
    events: [],
    search: "",
    selector: "",
    input:""
    };


  attendEvent = show => {
    API.attendConcert({
      userId: this.props.userId,
      concertId: show.id,
      artist: show.performance[0].artist.displayName,
      venue: show.venue.displayName,
      date: show.start.date,
      time: show.start.time,
      city: show.venue.metroArea.displayName,
      latitude: show.venue.lat,
      longitude: show.venue.lng,
    })
    .then(res => window.location.href = "/concerts/" + res.data._id)
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  handleRadioChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      selector: event.target.value
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (<>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col size="md-12">
<p>Hi {this.props.userId}</p>
```

**API.JS Code**

```
import axios from "axios";

export default {
    attendConcert: function(eventData) {
        return axios.post("/api/concerts", eventData);
    },
    getConcert: function(id) {
        return axios.get("/api/concerts/" + id);
    }
}
```

Note: some lines of code were removed to reduce the amount of code being presented but should one desire to see everything please let me know.

Comment: yeah userid will be null at first beause you defined null userid state at first and it will be setState(updated) later when your api throws response.
but your routh path has already been render before your api throws response. so you cand render path after userid has value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scope issue:

```
API.attendConcert({
      userId: this.props.userId,
      concertId: show.id,
      artist: show.performance[0].artist.displayName,
      venue: show.venue.displayName,
      date: show.start.date,
      time: show.start.time,
      city: show.venue.metroArea.displayName,
      latitude: show.venue.lat,
      longitude: show.venue.lng,
    })
```

`this` in that context is referring to the object literal you are building, not the component.

Declare a variable to hold the value of the `userId`, then use that value in the object literal, like this:

```
const userId = this.props.userId
API.attendConcert({
     userId: userId,
      concertId: show.id,
      artist: show.performance[0].artist.displayName,
      venue: show.venue.displayName,
      date: show.start.date,
      time: show.start.time,
      city: show.venue.metroArea.displayName,
      latitude: show.venue.lat,
      longitude: show.venue.lng,
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

As Binod has commented, you are getting `userId: null` as you initially set it to null in your state, and your code executes before the API call in app.js has time to come back due to async functionality. I recommend taking a look at this resource on [Asynchronous Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous).

Your `<Home />` component's props will update when you get a response, and will be passed down, so what you need to do is make sure `attendEvent()` is not called before the userId is passed down. Your current code does not show how this is being called at the moment, but I would assume it is in another `componentDidMount`. Try using [`componentDidUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) instead and checking if `props.userId !== null`, then make your API call `attendConcert`.

Hopefully this helps a bit, and if you have any more questions let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling the function from componentDidMount(). As everything is asynchronous. Your state are not set in the parent component and are being used in the child as props. I too have faced the same problem. Props get rendered in render() of child but not anywhere else.

**OR**

You could also use localStorage.

**OR**

Try this, place a null check before routing to home component.

```
   {this.state.userId ?
   <Route
      exact path="/home"
      render = {() => 
        <Home userId = {this.state.userId} /> : null}
```